# Wait for dialog click to restart an activity

Tags: android, android-intent, android-alertdialog

Hello everybody and thanks in advance for the help.

I have two activities. I´m calling a dialog in activity two from activity one.
The thing is that I want the dialog to restart activity one if positive button is pressed, but I can`t see how to do it.

This is my code...

Activity one:

```
    @Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.action_settings)
    {
        Funciones Funciones1 = new Funciones();

        Funciones1.MuestraDialogo(CluefichaActivity.this);

        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

Activity two:

```
public class Funciones extends Activity
```

{
    private static final int DIALOGO = 1;

```
private AlertDialog.Builder ventana;

Activity miActividad;





@Override
protected Dialog onCreateDialog(int id)
{
    switch (id)
    {
        case DIALOGO:
            ventana = new AlertDialog.Builder(miActividad);

            ventana.setIcon(miActividad.getResources().getIdentifier("my_icon", "drawable", miActividad.getPackageName()));
            ventana.setTitle("title");
            ventana.setMessage("message");

            ventana.setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener()
                {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int boton)
                    {
                            Intent intent = miActividad.getIntent();
                            miActividad.finish();
                            startActivity(intent);
                    }
                });
            }

            ventana.setNegativeButton("CANCEL", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener()
            {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int boton)
                {
                }
            });

            return ventana.create();
    }

    return null;
}
```

...
...

```
public void MuestraDialogo (Activity actividad)
{
    miActividad = actividad;

    showDialog(DIALOGO);
}
```

I get this error when I run it...

```
Process: com.myproject.projectname, PID: 1841
java.lang.NullPointerException
        at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:3511)
        at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:3472)
        at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:3714)
        at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:3682)
        at com.myproject.projectname.Funciones$1.onClick(Funciones.java:130)
        at com.android.internal.app.AlertController$ButtonHandler.handleMessage(AlertController.java:167)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:157)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5356)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1265)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1081)
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

where "Funciones.java:130" is this line of code: "startActivity(intent);"

Can anybody help, please? Thanks!

Comment: Bad programming practice for Android. You can not create Constructor of Activity, Like normal Java class.

Comment: I don't understand you, if you could be a little bit clearer please

Comment: `Funciones Funciones1 = new Funciones();` here `Funciones ` is Activity right? So you can not create object of activity like Java class in Android.

Comment: OK, but it's the only way I know to call Funciones' methods from another activity and get no errors. If I don't do this I get an error message, something like "Non static xxx method can't be called from static context", then if a put "static" on the method I'll get a lot of errors inside it. So I don't know a better option to do it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to send a broadcast (LocalBroadcast) from your sub-Activity dialog to your main activity and process that broadcast to instigate termination:

In your main `Activity`, say `MainActividad`

```
static final String BROADCAST_ACTIVITY_CLOSE = "com.example.ACTIVITY_CLOSE_BROADCAST";

private BroadcastReceiver broadcastReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        if(intent.getAction().equals(BROADCAST_ACTIVITY_CLOSE)) {
            terminateCleanly();
            finish();
        }
    }
};
```

Then in `onCreate`:

```
    LocalBroadcastManager broadcastManager = LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this);
    IntentFilter intentFilter = new IntentFilter();
    intentFilter.addAction(BROADCAST_ACTIVITY_CLOSE);
    broadcastManager.registerReceiver(broadcastReceiver, intentFilter);
```

Saves updating your manifest and I think is cleaner.

Your dialog invokes this with:

```
                Intent RTReturn = new Intent(MainActividad.BROADCAST_ACTIVITY_CLOSE);
                LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).sendBroadcast(RTReturn);
```

Comment: Thanks John, it works!, but one thing, Android Studio tells me about error in your line code "terminateCleanly()", don't know that, so I removed it, and also, I didn't want the activity to finish but restart, so I've changed "finish()" for my original piece of code "                Intent intent1 = getIntent();
                finish();
                startActivity(intent1);
"

Comment: `terminateCleanly()` is my own method, the one thing I meant to annotate/comment out. Just ignore it or replace with finish.. finish something, with the integer intent id you used to call `startActivityForResult` on your dialog, to close that too, if not already closed. Yep, yep restart is nearly finish so interchangeable, i actually call `recreate();` to restart my activity after reconfiguration.

Comment: OK, I thought terminateCleanly() it could be an Android Method from any Api that I didn't know.

Answer (score 2):

The problem you have is the intent of your old activity is null once you call finish on it. While John's answer is a cleaner way of terminating, the issue you are having is starting the activity again.

Try replacing

```
Intent intent = miActividad.getIntent();
startActivity(intent);
```

with

```
Intent newIntent = new Intent(Funciones.this, CluefichaActivity.class);
startActivity(newIntent);
```

Comment: Thanks Dave but I already had tried that and it didn't work, throws the same error "null pointer".